# Respond to an event in an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I have a bit of a complex situation that I am trying to find a solution for.

I have a web app that has a single module that then imports other classes. These classes handle building the UI and doing MVC-type work.

I have one class that builds a display of DIV elements. The name field in the div is contentEditable and I have some events that I use to allow me to select the text and then set the element to not be contentEditable when the user hits enter or there is a blur event.

All of this works quite well but I want to call back to a class when the DIV element has been edited and I can't figure out how to do it.

So my hierarchy is

- core.js - my main module
- displayList.js - the UI builder imported
- eventFunctions.js - imported by displayList to allow it to assign addListener events
- makeItemNonEditable() - the function that gets called

In the makeItemNonEditable() function I want to call to displayList so that this list knows that the UI element has been updated.

I have created a customEvent and added the appropriate handlers to the displayList class but it doesn't respond to the event. The addListener event is triggered and the event is being propagated as I can respond to it from core.js but not from the imported displayList.js class.

```js
import displayList from './displayList.js';
const objDisplayList = new displayList();

objDisplayList.addEventListener('nameChanged',objDisplayList.updateShipName);
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need to rework how I am propagating events?

**Update**

Just answering some of the questions below.

The custom event is being declared in eventFunctions.js and triggered as part of a blur event on the DIV the user is editing. So if the user causes a blur event or hits Enter then the nameChanged event is sent

```js
const nameChange = new Event('nameChanged');
```

```js
function makeItemNonEditable(event) {

    // set the item's contentEditable prop to false
    event.target.contentEditable = false;
    event.target.dispatchEvent(nameChange);
    
}
```

I am using the target of the blur event as the src of the event

`makeItemNonEditable` is called from an eventListener attached to the DIV when it is created

```js
// first the name field
let nameField = lastItem.querySelector('.displayName');
nameField.addEventListener('click', makeItemEditable);
nameField.addEventListener('blur', makeItemNonEditable);
nameField.addEventListener('keydown', testForEnter);
```

The display object creates the div and then attaches the eventListeners to it.

I have tried several different methods to try to get the displayList class as a target. I have extended the EventTarget class and also added `addEventListener` methods to the class.

At no point, and with no method I try, does the class get added as an eventListener. So when I run my app in a browser and use the `getAllEventListeners` method in the console I can see that the custom event is being added and my test hooks to it are there but not for the displayList class.

Comment: How are you firing the custom event?  Please show that code.  And, is this running in the browser?

Comment: Where are you calling `makeItemNonEditable`? How does it know about the particular `objDisplayList` instance?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `displayList`, please? How is it an event target? How do you fire the `nameChanged` event?

Comment: "*The display object creates the div and then attaches the eventListeners to it.*" - then it should also attach the `objDisplayList.updateShipName` to **that div**. (Or provide a method to do it, that can be called by the main module). You should not make the `displayList` class inherit from `EventTarget`.

Comment: So how would I go about attaching an object reference to a DIV?

Also, what is the issue with extending EventTarget? Other than the fact that it doesn't actually appear to work :-) ES6 added all of these event and dispatch classes but there doesn't appear to be wide support of using them outside of DOM objects

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to directly communicate between an ES6 class I have created and the DIVs that it creates as part of the process of creating the UI. Currently I have the DIVs dispatch an event and then the main code listens for that and then communicates with the displayList class. If possible I would like to avoid that. I come from a background of working in multimedia and most of the development environments there use events is a much broader way than JS does currently so I am having to learn to thing in JS

Comment: So apparently you can just make a new property and add it to a DOM object. So that solves that issue. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: Why "*go about attaching an object reference to a DIV*"? You want to attach the event listener to the div, on which the event is fired, not a reference to the object. "*ES6 added all of these event and dispatch classes*" - no, it didn't. They are classes provided by the DOM. "*Currently I have the DIVs dispatch an event and then the main code listens for that and then communicates with the displayList class. If possible I would like to avoid that.*" - why not just move the code that installs the listener inside the `displayList` class?

Comment: The alternative would be to have the `makeItemNonEditable` listener directly call the `updateShipName` method, but from what I understand, it doesn't have a reference to the `objDisplayList` instance. Maybe if you could provide a fuller example the picture would become clearer.

Comment: The code that attaches the listener is inside the displayList class but the methods that respond to them are not.

Comment: `updateShipName` is a `displayList` class method, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. I've actually got it working by adding a property to the DOM element when I create it. This allows me to call back to the displayFleet class directly.

Answer (score 0):

So as @Bergi mentions in the comments the most direct way to address this issue is to add a property to the DOM element which is a reference to the displayList object.

That works and is such a simple answer that I am kicking myself for not seeing it earlier.

The `makeItemNonEditable` function can then use that property to call back to the displayList object and send the target reference as well to make it all simpler.